# i an getting an error in my discord bot, please tell how fix

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, bots

I am coding a discord bot with the help  of Cody Lyons video on the basics of discord bot making:
[video](https://youtu.be/X_qg0Ut9nU8)

The Error:

```js
C:\Users\mdfar\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:544
      throw new TypeError('CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS');
      ^

TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.
    at Client._validateOptions (C:\Users\mdfar\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:544:13)
    at new Client (C:\Users\mdfar\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:73:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mdfar\bot\index.js:2:13)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS'
```

my Code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

const token = 'OTIwOTQ3OTM1MjQyNTAyMTU1.Ybrxmg.lcPJbRn-xqIvsVieOt7emiAjD4w';

bot.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('This Bot Is Online');
})

bot.login(token);
```

Help PLease I'm using node js for this

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide intents since Discordjs v13

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });
```

I suggest you read the full article [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#enabling-intents)